# Detect which controller has been popped in root view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Is it possible to detect which 'UIViewController' has been popped in the root view controller? I have 3 view controllers, A->B->C. Both B and C have popping actions. Is it possible to detect whether it was B or C was popped in A?

Comment: You can set it by simple `NSUserDefaults` flag, that would be easiest way to do things like this.

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter` OR `NSUserDefaults` for this.

Comment: I would set A controller as a **UINavigationControllerDelegate** and implement: *- navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:* or *- navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:*

Comment: @DanielS Assuming you want to look at the navigation stack in those methods, it won't work. When `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` gets called, the navigation stack (navigationController.viewControllers) is already modified. (In the case of popToRoot, only the rootViewController will be in it).

Comment: @LordZsolt yes, you're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I much rather prefer using delegate for this over something likfe `NSNotificationCenter` or `NSUserDefaults`.

You define a protocol, which has a method like this:

```
- (void)willPopToRootFromViewController(UIViewController *)fromViewController;
```

You implement this method in A, and the other view controllers call this method before popping.

You can find a complete example on how to implement a delegate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c).

Comment: How would you access 'A" in 'B'? I had a look at that link, very helpful

Comment: What do you mean? `fromViewController` would be the view controller you're popping from (aka `B` or `C`) and self will be `A`

Comment: I mean how would you call the above method?

Comment: That's what the delegate is for. You would have a **weak** property to a class which implements that protocol (in that case your A object).